# How to run a timer in the background ?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have code for a timer , but if i change fragment the timer was reset to 00:00 i want that timer still count after i click stop or pause or that mean this timer still count in the background 
how to do it ? 
this is my code,

```
public class TimerFragment extends BaseFragment {
    private Button startButton;
    private Button pauseButton;
    private TextView timerValue;
    private long startTime = 0L;
    private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
    long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
    long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    long updatedTime = 0L;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timer, container, false);

        initialize();
        //when start

        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);

        //pause
        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
                customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;

            timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", secs));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }

    };
```

thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :-**  When you switch fragment and come back to Timer Fragment, the onCreate lifecycle callback will be called and that gone reset your timer in

> customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);

**Solution :-** Move timer logic to Activity class but activity will be recreate in orientation change so move timer logic into Application class :-

Drop this class in you project  package

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Application;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class App extends Application {

    public static App appInstance;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        appInstance = this;

        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    }

    public void afficher() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), dateFormat.format(new Date()), 300).show();
        handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
    }

    public void startTimer() {
        runnable.run();
    }

    public void stopTimer() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            afficher();
        }
    };

}
```

Set your **Application name** to **App class** like this below (android name property of application) :-

```
   <application
        android:name="com.masterdetail_webview.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.masterdetail_webview.TimertestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Now you can start and stop timer simply like this from anywhere

```
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            App.appInstance.startTimer();

        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            App.appInstance.stopTimer();

        }
    });
```

Adding AppController

[image]

Comment: java lang null pointer exception when i call  App.appInstance.startTimer();
sorry i newbie in android :(

Comment: You must declare Application name in manifest see edit for reference 
    <application
        android:name="<your package name>.App"

Comment: It's a good solution to move the logic to application scope, the problem if he needs to show the time in the fragment, for that you will need access for the ui of the fragment. I think it would be better to change startTimer() to startTimer(Hanlder handler) and implement the handler in the fragment

Comment: @visionixvisionix ok mate i will try that

Comment: Thanks for the timer logic.

Comment: Unfortunately the timer will start to "skip" seconds the moment the phone enters sleep. So this is not a good solution if you want the timer to run even when the phone enters sleep.