# Run CountDownTimer on background

Tags: android

I want to show a blocking activity after 2 hours of using the app and when the app is paused the countTimer should paused, How can I do this ?

Comment: so you want to monitor how long your app is in foreground and do something after 2 hours of foreground time? This is not trivial since if have more than one Activity it will be come difficult to determine if the app is in foreground. [This article](https://medium.com/@mohitsharma_49363/android-detect-app-foreground-time-9b4f6752b077) may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? Maybe you can just start a background Counter-thread which runs in parallel to your UI thread. Of course, you then need a mechanism to inform this thread when the state of your app is "paused". Take a look at: https://developer.android.com/guide/background
Maybe this post can also help you? [How to run a timer in the background ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36931965/how-to-run-a-timer-in-the-background)